# Use QColorDialog to return RGB565 value

Tags: c++, qt, rgb, qcolordialog

I want to return an RGB565 value when a user selects a color from a QColorDialog. I tried to use the conversion method described from the [RGB565 Color Picker website](http://www.barth-dev.de/online/rgb565-color-picker/#) but the output of my code does not represent the same value in hex format:

```cpp
QColor color = QColorDialog::getColor();

uint8_t red = color.red();
uint8_t green = color.green();
uint8_t blue = color.blue();
qDebug("%d red + %d green + %d blue", red, green, blue);

uint16_t Rgb565 = 0;
Rgb565 = (((red & 0xf8)<<8) + ((green & 0xfc)<<3) + (blue>>3));
qDebug() << Rgb565;
```

For example, if the RGB values were `(255, 0, 0)`, the output is `63488`. I was expecting the output to be `0xF800`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: use `uint8_t` for red/green/blue and `uint16_t` for Rbg565 [like the link you posted says] instead to keep things unsigned and in range.

Comment: @MikeVine - Thanks for that, unfortunately I still do not get the expected result.

Comment: You get exactly the right result. `0xF800` in hexadecimal is the same numerical value as `63488` in decimal. How you print it out (and it seems like qDebug prints out in decimal by default which is a sensible default) doesn't change that fact.

Comment: @MikeVine - I did not know qDebug does that by default. You're right, using `qDebug() << hex << Rgb565;` returns the hex value. If you can post an answer, I'll accept it.